# Extending class type is not assignable to base class type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Base<TAttributes extends {} = {}> {
    constructor(attributes: TAttributes) {}
}

class Extended extends Base<{test: string}> {

}

function test(test: typeof Base) {};

test(Extended);
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to create a function, which expects a constructor of `Base` class type, and I am trying to pass it constructors of more specific (extended) types. Unfortunatly, because of the generics, typescript complains, that:

> Argument of type 'typeof Extended' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Base'.
> Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
> Type 'new (attributes: { test: string; }) => Extended' is not assignable to type 'new <TAttributes extends {} = {}>(attributes: TAttributes) => Base'.
> Types of parameters 'attributes' and 'attributes' are incompatible.
> Type 'TAttributes' is not assignable to type '{ test: string; }'.
> Property 'test' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ test: string; }'

I can't figure out, what am I doing wrongly here. If I remove the generic parameters from the base class, typescript is not complaining anymore. Could someone point me in the direction, on how to achieve my desired outcome?

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=39#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAggFwwJwJYCMBXDBGBADxIDsATGAbwF9oBeaJgPnYCho-pgAeyoQchYBkHYAFGCx4iJCAC5o6eQWKkAlO0bd93UJBgBRSgloIa0CtTpxESekoyrReKgHNGXetwMAgDNCKglcYWhXaVdVDABPAAcEQSDHCARdJgBuAOjze2ttbKA) link also.

Comment: The constructor of an extending class is not necessarily assignable to `Base`'s constructor (it could take totally different arguments). What do you need exactly?

Comment: Please proof read your first paragraph for clarity. Also, what do you do with the parameter in the function?

Comment: @GuerricP I am trying to create a function, that can use the static side of the base class.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai you should add this information into your question as it actually describes your full problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use only the `static` methods from a base `class` and not its `constructor`, you can use a `NoConstructor` helper type in order to keep only the properties from the base class, and remove the constructor function part of it:

```
class Base<TAttributes extends {} = {}> {
    static log() {
        console.log('log');
    }
    constructor(attributes: TAttributes) { }
}

class Extended extends Base<{ test: string }> {

}

type NoConstructor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

function test(test: NoConstructor<typeof Base>) {
    test.log(); // OK
};

test(Extended); // OK
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAggFwwJwJYCMBXDBGBADxIDsATGAbwF9oBeaJgPnYCho-oIGMBlzBoIAPYBzABQBKHvyXRgEqhAkgEAOkmyA5Hv1yA3L36NzfVepyFgGCdhnCcBYqQBc0dFjxESCAV6aEtLblBIGABRSgRaBBpoCmo6OEQkEMCMb0E8KilQrnpubnCMAE8ABwRoADkJAGE1PPtHbFQuNgAFUQBrVAAaaD6ECokAMx8OM24JwioHXDVobJls7wbm22w2pyRKmsn0iAQOYKtV0gxdaXkzRlm12NTE0yA)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the implementation of `test()`. How could you possibly know what arguments to pass to the constructor?

In your example `Base` could be instantiated by:

```
new Base()
```

But `Extended` requires a `{ test: string }` argument.

```
new Extended({ test: 'qwe' })
```

So you cannot treat the `Extended` constructor like the `Base` constructor. It has a different type.

Instances of a child class are always assignable to types of the parent class, but the same is *not* true for constructors which can change drastically.

You could do something like:

```
function test<
  Args extends unknown[],
  Instance extends unknown
>(
  ctor: new (...args: Args) => Instance,
  ...args: Args
): Instance {
  return new ctor(...args)
}
```

In this example, the test function takes a `ctor` (any constructor) and `args` (the arguments that constructor requires). And then returns whatever `Instance` types that constructor makes.

```
// works
test(Base, {});
test(Extended, { test: 'qwe' });
```

But this will work with any constructor, and not just whatever some `Base` is.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=33&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAggFwwJwJYCMBXDBGBADxIDsATGAbwF9oBeaJgPnYFgAoaAdGAB7KhByFgGYdgAUYLHiIkIALmjpFBYqQCU7Rn0O8+oSDACilBLQQ1oFanTiIk9FRnXi8VAOaMuej4jYN4AM0IqKVxRaA8kPgE0bF8ya1oYSIBrKmEAdyoAbQBdABpE6ABJMQwwKIQHdOds3IK+DlkKqRl1KgQ86FkAOhGwFLVoZNT9Fi5q8TrgBHL+aBGhsdT1KYg+XXV52vqeVewEDEJsKmg+ge65dc2IXRCTXg9ZeAhlg10Abj4HysTjspXYcVInmgAHIAI55BDQ6CMf5AA)